# Are there situations that a crashed Android app's task will remain running in the background?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, crashes, ram, resource-monitoring, crash-reports

Quick question to help me understand how my phone's performance is affected when an app terminates "irregularly".

When an Android app crashes (or otherwise terminates irregularly), could the task keep running even though it's inaccessible?

For example, when a Windows app (like Excel) crashes either "on it's own," or because of a programmatic error on my part, and I then restart Excel, the *Windows Task Manager* will sometimes show 2 or more instances of the application (sucking up resources even though the extra windows aren't visible/accessible) until I manually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>→<kbd>End Task</kbd> or Reboot.

### My question(s) are:

- Can the same thing happen when an Android app crashes?
- If multiple instances were indeed running, would multiples show in `Android Task Manager`?
- The <kbd>Clear Memory</kbd> button in `RAM Manager`isn't exactly descriptive of *what* it's "clearing".  Is it doing anything helpful in cases like these?
- Are the answers to these questions affected by whether or not the crash produces the standard `Unfortunately, xxxxxx has stopped. Report/OK` dialog (as opposed to just returning to the home screen)?
- Is there a better method for keeping an eye on resource usage that might not be easily identified with builtin Android `Task Manager`?

A quick explanation (or a point in the right direction) would be appreciated... As a coder (but not for Android!) the info I've found is either too [simplified](http://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/smartphones/droid/android-phone-task-manager-functions/) or too [advanced](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html) to answer my questions.  :)

I'm running Kitkat 4.4.4 on Samsung Galaxy 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the app crashes the app will restart most probably by default and continue in background.
- You cannot run multiple instances of the same app in android.
- The clear memory button is used to free the memory occupied by all open apps and the apps will restart.
- Don't do it frequently because the apps will occupy the space again and it will take more power and processing power to free the memory and reload the apps.
- You don't need to be concerned with resource usage, android os is smart enough. Just make sure you don't keep unnecessary apps on your phone and huge media files that are not required.

Comment: That's what I needed to know, thank you!  The only part I'm unclear on is the difference in a crash that displays the `"Unfortunately xxxxx has stopped"` dialog, versus just returning to the home screen.